# Dynamically and Programatically Uncheck a CheckboxCell

Tags: gwt

I have a `Datagrid` with a `CheckboxCell` column. There will be some rows that cannot be checked, and the way I would like to implement this would be to handle the "checked" event and cancel it if some criteria is met. Here is the code I have tried:

```
Column<Job, Boolean> selectColumn = new Column<Job, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell()) {
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(Job job) {
        // do I uncheck the cell here?
        return JobDataGrid.this.jobSelection.isSelected(job);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Cell.Context context, Element elem, Job object, NativeEvent event)
    {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, object, event);
        String eventType = event.getType();
        if ("change".equals(eventType)) {
            // do I uncheck the cell here?
        }
    }
};
```

How do I handle the event and set the checkbox to be unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the change in a checkbox, you can simply cancel the native event inside your `onBrowserEvent` method:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Note that if you don't update your object when a checkbox is clicked, you can always refresh() your DataGrid and the checkbox will be displayed in its original state.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. Is there something I'm missing? I put `event.preventDefault();` in the method but I am still able to check the checkbox cells. Do I also need to call `event.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: Try to call "super" only in cells where you want the change to take place. If it does not work, then remove 'onBrowserEvent' completely, and simply call 'refresh' in the field value updater after you updated - or not, based on your criteria - the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a check box uncheckable, from the UX perspective it is better be **disabled**.

You can create a custom check box cell where you can control every aspect of rendering of the element including disabled state:

```
public class UncheckableCheckboxCell extends CheckboxCell {

    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

        @Template("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" checked/>")
        SafeHtml INPUT_CHECKED();

        @Template("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\"/>")
        SafeHtml INPUT_UNCHECKED();

        @Template("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" disabled=\"disabled\"/>")
        SafeHtml INPUT_UNCHECKED_DISABLED();
    }
    private static UncheckableCheckboxCell.Template template = GWT.create(UncheckableCheckboxCell.Template.class);

  public UncheckableCheckboxCell(boolean dependsOnSelection, boolean handlesSelection) {
    super(dependsOnSelection, handlesSelection);
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, Boolean value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    // Get the view data.
    Object key = context.getKey();
    Boolean viewData = getViewData(key);
    if (viewData != null && viewData.equals(value)) {
      clearViewData(key);
      viewData = null;
    }

    if (value != null && ((viewData != null) ? viewData : value)) {
      sb.append(template.INPUT_CHECKED());
    } else if (value == null) {
      //use null value as an indicator of unchecked and disable state
      sb.append(template.INPUT_UNCHECKED_DISABLED());
    } else {
      sb.append(template.INPUT_UNCHECKED());
    }
  }

}
```

Then inside your getValue() method you can return null when you want the check box to be unchecked/disabled:

```
@Override
public Boolean getValue(Job job) {
    // is my job checkable?
    if (job.checkable()) {
       //return null explicitly so my custom cell knows it should be rendered as disabled 
       return null;
    } else { 
       return JobDataGrid.this.jobSelection.isSelected(job);
    }
}
```